# Object.assign (REACT) output incorrect and not working as expected

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

Guys I have a project on react that have 3 components , and I have to take the state of this 3 pages and mount one JSON in a final page.

My components are not child and parents, so the solution that I Found was set the state to Localstorage, get the state and transform in Json, It worked, I Have my JSONs but I Need to combine theese JSONs into ONE, 
I tried concat, but it didn't work, and I'm trying with Object.assign I Saw some examples and Documentation but it's not working for me, and I can't see why.

JSON 1:

```
{
"A1_EMAIL": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
"formErrors": {
    "A1_EMAIL": "",
    "A1_CGC": ""
},
"A1_EMAILVALID": ["xxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxx", "wwwww.", "com"],
"A1_CGCVALID": false,
"showError": false,
"showErrorCGC": false,
"A1_CGC": "328114xxx14000197",
"A1_NOME": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"A1_NREDUZ": "sssaaaaa",
"A1_SITUA": "ATIVA",
"A1_DTNASC": "19/02/2019",
"NaturezaJ": "213-5 - Empresário (Individual)",
"AtividadePrincipal": "62.01-5-01",
"AtividadeSecundária": "Suporte técnico, manutenção e outros serviços em tecnologia da informação",
"A1_CEP": "04.550-003",
"A1_BAIRRO": "Vila Olímpia",
"A1_EST": "SP",
"A1_END": "xxxxx",
"A1_MUN": "São Paulo",
"checked": true,
"A1_ENDCOB": "gwwwwwww",
"A1_CEPC": "04.550-003",
"A1_BAIRROC": "Vila Olímpia",
"A1_MUNC": "São Paulo"
```

}

JSON 2:

```
{
"U5_CONTAT": "e3e3",
"U5_EMAIL": "e3e3",
"A1_INSCR": "fr",
"U5_FONE": "rr"
```

}

OUTPUT that I'm getting:

```
{0: "{", 1: """, 2: "U", 3: "5", 4: "_", 5: "C", 6: "O", 7: "N", 8: "T", 9: "A", 10: "T", 11: """, 12: ":", 13: """, 14: "e", 15: "3", 16: "e", 17: "3", 18: """, 19: ",", 20: """, 21: "U", 22: "5", 23: "_", 24: "E", 25: "M", 26: "A", 27: "I", 28: "L", 29: """, 30: ":", 31: """, 32: "e", 33: "3", 34: "e", 35: "3", 36: """, 37: ",", 38: """, 39: "A", 40: "1", 41: "_", 42: "I", 43: "N", 44: "S", 45: "C", 46: "R", 47: """, 48: ":", 49: """, 50: "f", 51: "r", 52: """, 53: ",", 54: """, 55: "U", 56: "5", 57: "_", 58: "F", 59: "O", 60: "N", 61: "E", 62: """, 63: ":", 64: """, 65: "r", 66: "r", 67: """, 68: "}", 69: ":", 70: """, 71: """, 72: "}", 73: ",", 74: """, 75: "A", 76: "1", 77: "_", 78: "E", 79: "M", 80: "A", 81: "I", 82: "L", 83: "V", 84: "A", 85: "L", 86: "I", 87: "D", 88: """, 89: ":", 90: "[", 91: """, 92: "g", 93: "r", 94: "u", 95: "p", 96: "o", 97: "h", 98: "p", 99: "s", …}
```

My Code:

```
var JSON1 = localStorage.getItem('JSONCLIENTE 1')
var JSON2 = localStorage.getItem('JSONCLIENTE 2')
var newObj = Object.assign({}, JSON1,JSON2)

        console.log('Json 1:')
        console.log(JSON1)
        console.log('Json 2:')
        console.log(JSON2)
        console.log('Converted Object 2:')
        console.log(newObj)
```

What Am I doing wrong

Comment: `getItem` returns a string, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because **json** it's a string. You need turn **json** into an **js-object**. Use `JSON.parse()`

```
var JSON1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('JSONCLIENTE 1'))
var JSON2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('JSONCLIENTE 2'))
var newObj = Object.assign({}, JSON1,JSON2)

    console.log('Json 1:')
    console.log(JSON1)
    console.log('Json 2:')
    console.log(JSON2)
    console.log('Converted Object 2:')
    console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the localStorage data is always a string so you may need to use `JSON.parse` when retrieving from localStorage as well.

If the keys are not the same in both the JSON, you can try something like

```js
var a = {
  message: 'Hello'
};

var b = {
  text: 'Hi'
};

var c = {
  ...a,
  ...b
};

console.log(c);
```